# AutoCompleteTextView with multiple touchable areas and dpad navigation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have an `AutoCompleteTextView`. I want each suggestion to offer the option to remove it. An item should look a bit like the items of your dial log with the call option on the right. So, the point is, each item has two clickable areas.

I have managed to make it work for touch input with some near hacking. Because I can't reach the `ListView` held by the `AutoCompleteTextView`'s popup, I needed to call `AutoCompleteTextView.onCommitCompletion()` from an `OnClickListener` of the main item view. So, this all seems to work fine, but:

I have checked out my app with the keyboard and that is quite messed up: The arrow keys focus the entire suggestion items one by one but I can neither focus my custom primary item nor my "remove item". Also, when I press enter nothing happens.

The dpad navigation works fine in the call log of the dialer app but that's a plain `ListView`, so can this work for `AutoCompleteTextView` at all? And how?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make a custom adapter for the list? If my memory is good, you can apply a custom layout with many buttons and listeners on your view in the custom adapter.

Comment: Yes, it's a BaseAdapter based adapter (uaha!) with a custom layout. Everything works as expected but the dpad (or hardware keyboard) input.